# Need clarification: \tkzInterCC[with nodes] in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

Meaning of this (Unable to find in tkz-euclide manual)

```
\tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,D,I)(E,D,I)   \tkzGetPoints{H'}{H}
```

> CODE from 
>   http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/euclide.html

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-6,xmax=12,ymin=-6,ymax=6] 
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoint(-5,-5){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}  
    \tkzDefPoint(+5,-5){B} 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,-5){F}    
    \tkzDefPoint(+5,0){F'}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,+5){E} 
    \tkzDefPoint(-5,0){K}
    \tkzDefSquare(A,B)         \tkzGetPoints{C}{D}

    \tkzInterLC(D,C)(E,B)      \tkzGetPoints{T'}{T}

    \tkzDefMidPoint(D,T)     \tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,D,I)(E,D,I)   \tkzGetPoints{H'}{H}
    \tkzInterLC(O,H)(O,E)     \tkzGetPoints{M'}{M}
    \tkzInterCC(O,E)(E,M)     \tkzGetPoints{Q}{M}
    \tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,O,E)(Q,E,M)    \tkzGetPoints{P}{E}
    \tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,O,E)(P,E,M)    \tkzGetPoints{N}{Q} 

    \tkzCompass(O,H)
    \tkzCompass(E,H)
    \tkzDrawArc[color=gray,style=dashed](E,B)(T)  
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,E)  
    \tkzDrawSegments[color=gray](O,H E,H E,F F',K)
    \tkzDrawPoints(T,M,Q,P,N)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[color=red](M,E,Q,P,N)   
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX I believe the OP is asking for `\tkzInterCC`, which should be from Chapter 10.3. :)

Comment: @RuixiZhang You're right. I wanted to say the chapter, but I copy-pasted the (wrong) section!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry but you're right: the documentation is incomplete. There are three options for the intersection of circles "N", "R" or "with nodes". The name of the options is not very good, the order of my examples is not good and finally it lacks an explanation for the third option.

N means Node The circles are defined by two points (nodes)
as (A, B) and (B, A) circles of center A passing through B and circle of center B passing through A.

R means radius You give a point and a radius (length).

Finally "with nodes" you need three points (nodes): the center then two points to define the radius. With (A, B, C), A is the center and BC gives the radius.
Currently there is no documentation in English.
An example with the main options with next version of tkz-euclide:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,fullpage}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,5){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(54:5){F}
  \tkzDrawCircle[color=gray](A,C) 
  \tkzInterCC[with nodes](A,A,C)(C,B,F) \tkzGetPoints{a}{e}
  \tkzInterCC(A,C)(a,e)                 \tkzGetFirstPoint{b}
  \tkzInterCC(A,C)(b,a)                 \tkzGetFirstPoint{c}
  \tkzInterCC(A,C)(c,b)                 \tkzGetFirstPoint{d}
  \tkzDrawPoints(a,b,c,d,e)  
  \tkzDrawPolygon[color=red](a,b,c,d,e)
  \foreach \vertex/\num in {a/36,b/108,c/180,d/252,e/324}{%
  \tkzDrawPoint(\vertex)
  \tkzLabelPoint[label=\num:$\vertex$](\vertex){}% astuce   
  \tkzDrawSegment[color=gray,style=dashed](A,\vertex)
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately as a result of health problem, I can not stay very long in front of a computer. I tried to finalize an update and write documentation in English but I did not succeed. I am currently retrying to finish this work

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunate that the [`tkz-euclide`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) manual is in French (and you can find it on CTAN). But I would guess it represents “intersections between two circles”. You can also find a comment [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/intersecting-arcs/) just above `\tkzInterCC(A,A,D)(B,B,F){H}{I}`, which says `% Find the intersection of the two arcs`.

**Update**: Indeed, Section 10.3, which is titled “Intersection de deux cercles”, documents the command `\tkzInterCC`.

Comment: +1. Some perhaps more direct evidence for your statement comes from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17316/121799) by the author.

Comment: 10.3 Intersection of two circles
The most frequent case is that of two circles defined by their center and a point, but as previously option R allows to use the radius measurements ... Options N and R only.

Comment: All examples use only \tkzInterCC[R].

Answer (score 1):

> From tkz-2d manual page no 126 Example 122

```
\tkzInterCC[with nodes](center,node1,node2)(center,node1,node2)
```

**here radius = length between node1 and node 2.**

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(3,3){B} 
\tkzDrawCircle[color=blue](A,B)  
\tkzDrawCircle[color=red](B,A)
% Find the intersection of the two circles
% \tkzInterCC[with nodes](center,node1,node2)(center,node1,node2)  
% here radius = length between node1 and node 2.
\tkzInterCC[with nodes](A,A,B)(B,B,A)    \tkzGetPoints{M}{N} 
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](M,N)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A,B)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,M,N)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]